# Variable Data Length in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm doing a project, to help develope a Hardware in the loop application for Audioprocessing.

In this project, i will recieve some configuration through UDP from PC, and the UDP datapakage contains something like "FFT Length", thus i should implement a Simulink model, that set the FFT Length or "Data Length" dynamicly.

Here is the thing i already have ( It is TI C6455 DSK Board):

1. UDP Server is already implemented and packed as a Subsystem with one output Port (Signal), whitch is the FFT Length recieved
2. the Simulink ADC and DAC Block for the Boards, with fixed Sample per Frame (linke 256 Samples per Frame, and Sample Rate of 48kHz)
3. FFT Block with the FFT Length set to "Inherit FFT Length from Input"

now i'm considering using Buffer-Block to implement that, but there i have some troubles:

1. Buffer-Block don't have a Port whitch can dynamicly change the output length
2. Buffer-Block caused the unstable Spectrum output

Anyone can help me, so that i can solve both problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the relation between FFT length and your frame length of 256? Do you basically need to re-buffer your data to FFT length or is FFT length just used for some analysis where you can truncate or pad data to the 256 samples?

Comment: I basically need to rebuffer my data to FFT length for analysis. Because i recieve 256 samples each frame from the ADC.

Comment: I cannot think of an easy way to do this. One possibility is to create large buffer and then send data to MATLAB Function block where you use MATLAB code to loop inside the buffered data and calculate several fft's at the same time.